# Best closed convex surface fitting N points in 3D

Tags: statistics, differential-geometry, 3d, computational-geometry

First. It's easier to understand the problem by describing the application where it arises from.

We have a convex body $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and measure points on its surface. The measurements are noisy. We need to reconstruct the body from these measurements. It's dangerous to do this just by considering $Hull(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{N})$, because not all points are vertexes of $Hull(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{N})$.

---

Now we state it as a mathematical problem.

Suppose that N points $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{N}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ are given (and they are so that $O = (0, 0, 0)$ is the interior point of $Hull(O, x_{1}, \ldots, x_{N})$).

Let's consider the set $\mathfrak{M}$ of all **closed convex surfaces** $M$ that have the following property: $O = \{0, 0, 0\} \in Int \overline{M}$, where $\overline{M}$ is a convex body whose bondary is $M$, i. e. $\partial \overline{M} = M$

It's needed to find such $M \in \mathfrak{M}$ that minimizes the sum of distances from $x_{i}$ to $M$ for all $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{N}$.

$$
I(M) = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{N} \rho(x_{i}, M) \to inf \;\;\; s.t. M \in \mathfrak{M}
$$

It's obvious that it is enough to consider not whole $\mathfrak{M}$, but only polyhedrons, because if $M^{*} = argmin \; I(M)$ then one can construct a polyhedron $P^{*}$ such that $I(M^{*}) = I(P^{*})$ just by finding such $y_{i} \in M^{*}$ so that $\rho(x_{i}, M^{*}) = \rho(x_{i}, y_{i})$ and then $P^{*} = Hull(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{N})$.

Does anybody know any method to find such best surface or polyhedron?

---

NOTE: It is not a convex hull. Here is the contrary instance:
[image]

If you consider the convex hull, then it's possible to find better surface by dropping 3 exterior points and considering the convex hull of the rest points. It will have better value of the inital functional.

Comment: I honestly tried to read your question multiple times, but I still don't see why building a convex hull from $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_N$ isn't ok.

Comment: Ah, now I see why: because convex hull of these points doesn't have to contain origin. But I think it's stil manageable. Also, do you mean "convex bodies(domains)" instead of "convex surfaces"? Because surface have an empty interior w.r.t. ambient Euclidean topology.

Comment: Yes. We consider only such surfaces that $O \in M$. If i write "convex bodies" then i will need to change the definition of functional: $I(M) = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{N} \rho(x_{i}, \partial M)$.

Comment: Sorry. I have wrong formulation. Not interior of $M$, but the interior part of space $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ - each closed $M$ divides $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ onto 2 parts - interior and exterior.

Comment: Now it's fixed.

Comment: I still think it's better call it convex body, not surface, but that's up to you. I have a suspicion that sometimes this infimum is not reachable in this class. Every convex body (or surface) from you class must contain a convex hull of points $O, x_1, \dots, x_N$. If $O$ is an interior point of this convex hull, then (I believe) we are done: it's a solution. If $O$ is a border point, then it's where the problem might come: I think convex hull of points $O, x_1, \dots, x_N$ it minimizes your functional, but it's some sort of a "limit point" for your set $\mathfrak{M}$.

Comment: Yes. I have forgotten to say that only such configuration of points that $O$ is th interior point of $Hull(O, x_{1}, \ldots, x_{N})$. This assumption is implicit in our application.

Comment: What is it you're minimizing?  The entire space includes all the points mentioned.

Comment: Oh. Maybe it will be better to describe the application where this question arises from. We have a real body in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and then observe $N$ points on its border. But the observations are noisy, so they are not in convex state (not all points are the vertexes of the convex hull $Hull(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{N})$)

Comment: The problem of [reconstructing surfaces from scattered point sets](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall13b/Papers/Schall05.pdf) is well studied in computer graphics. You could try the [Eigencrust](http://graphics.berkeley.edu/papers/Kolluri-SSR-2004-07/) algorithm which is quite resistant to outliers.

Comment: Yes, @Rahul, but computer graphics does not consider the problem of reconstruction of **convex** surface. The article you have mentioned presents the algorithm of reconstruction of surface from the noisy measured point set. But in our problem we know _a priori_ that the surface is convex, and if we apply Eigencrust algorithm, it will return non-convex body. I need the algorithm that always reconstructs only a convex body.

Comment: Well, if the points come from a convex surface with a few outliers, then the Eigencrust algorithm is likely to yield the same convex surface. If you want to guarantee convexity you can take its convex hull.